# VBA Range not being assigned to an Array

Tags: vba, excel

So rather simply I defined a test function:

```
Option Base 1
Function TestFunction(InputRange As Range)
    Dim TestArray() As Variant
    TestArray = InputRange

    Debug.Print TestArray(5)
End Function
```

I then call it on a sheet with =TestFunction(A:A), and expect to see the value in  row 5 printed to the Immediate window. Instead I don't get any output. The first 100 or so rows of A have data so I'd expect TestArray(5) to output something.

I've also tried changing the above to:

```
    TestArray = InputRange.Value
```

and:

```
    TestArray = Range(InputRange)
```

None of this seems to work.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print TestArray(5,1)`  Though it is one column it is still a two dimensional array

Comment: @ScottCraner is correct about that (though you could declare it simple as `TestArray` rather than `TestArray()` when you set it equal to `InputRange.Value`. I hope that you don't try to assign `A:A` to a variant in real code -- that would be an array with over a million entries

Comment: That was my issue. Thank you so much! If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it. @ScottCraner

Comment: @JohnColeman Don't worry I plan to trim the range to its actual size before assigning it to an array.

Comment: I wrote a function for taking these pseudo two dimensional arrays and converting them into one dimensional arrays. Sometimes I use the function, more often then not I just live with the annoying index. Still, you might find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31144434/4996248

Comment: Neat, I may use this. Thanks @JohnColeman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when assigning a range to an array it is made into a two dimensional array regardless if it is one column or one row.  So all references must refer to it as a two dimensional array:

```
Debug.Print TestArray(5,1)
```